# Should I build my own parts for making PCB with eagle or is there a database somewhere?

Tags: pcb-design, components, stepper-motor, eaglecad

I'm trying to build a custom PCB for a project I'm working on. I'm building a small robot that navigates using a color sensor and moves using two motors. For logic I'm using an Arduino Nano. 
My problem is that I can't find the following parts:

1. 28BYJ-48 5V Stepper Motor.
2. TCS3200 color sensor.

I've found this [site](http://sparkle.tribbeck.com/eaglesearch2/), but cant find them there. I also tried to search github, but with out any luck.

It seems strange to my, if nobody else have made a stepper motor and then shared it?! So I'm wondering if I'm looking in the wrong places?

Another question is of its worth the trouble to learn to make my own parts with Eagle?

Comment: It would help if you suggest what parts are required that are missing from the standard Eagle libraries.

Comment: This will speed things up too if you're doing your own parts (free version) http://www.pcblibraries.com/

Comment: Also, the EAGLE website offers a large number of user-contributed libs. And often, there are other parts with same symbol and package as your parts, so you can use them. If you don't find something suitable, it's also a good exercise to make your own libs.

Comment: "Parts" in Eagle are largely things that can go on a PCB.  Is the stepper motor supposed to go on the PCB?  I'm sure there are situations where you would mount one on a PCB, but in this case, I think you're talking about including some sort of breakout to wire up the stepper motor, or maybe a header.  There are plenty of headers in the "PINHEAD" library

Comment: Good point on the stepper. I only need to some sort of breakout. The color sensor and steppers will have their own Arduino Nano and be separated on two different PCBs.The two PCBs will be connected through some rx/tx communication.

Comment: @SomeHardwareGuy. As far as I can see, https://www.pcblibraries.com only works for windows?

Comment: I've only ever used in windows so that might be true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parts are difficult to make standard; depending on technology used to make a PCB certain features must be resized while certain other features must stay the same. Also, the  libraries included with the editor are often too large to be useful - you spend more time looking for a part than what it would take to draw one from scratch. On the other hand, redrawing everything would be silly. Make your own libraries, copy included parts as needed, i.e., only ones you're actually using, and draw the parts which are not included. Sparkfun has nice tutorials on Eagle libraries.